# Need to reference a local variable before assigning

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a permutation algorithm that will be used for a traveling sales person kind of problem. I have a method to calculate the cost of the cycle that will call a method (currentBest) to see if this permutation is better than currentBest one.

```
    def currentBest(newCost):
        if newCost < currentBest:
            currentBest = newCost
        return currentBest
```

But the first time i run though this code currentBest will not have a value so i guess i have to assign it a value first but it has to remember the currentBest value for the other permutation so making a currentBest = 999 at the top of the code I don't think will work.

Thank you

Comment: There are no static local variables in Python; try converting this to an object and using an instance variable and give it an initial value, e.g. `self.currentBest = 999`.

Comment: The fact that you want to do this indicates that you are doing something the hard way. Don't make currentBest a function. Put that code directly into the function which is calling currentBest right now. If your code is ugly/repetitive in that case then post it at codereview.stackexchange.com and they will tell how to clean it up.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to find the smallest value in a list, just do:

```
>>> min([9,2,4,8,5,6])
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a magic number, initialise `currentBest` with Python's `None`.

You should then check whether `currentBest is None` and if it is, you can assign it the value of `newCost` and continue.

E.g (in Python 2.7 and 3.2):

```
>>> currentBest = None
>>> def current_best(newCost):
...     global currentBest
...     if currentBest is None or newCost < currentBest:
...         currentBest = newCost
...     return currentBest
... 
>>> current_best(3)
3
>>> current_best(4)
3
>>> current_best(2)
2
```

But really you should probably use [`min()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min):

```
>>> min([3, 4, 2])
2
```

Comment: As written but not if the comparison is currentBest is None or newCost < currentBest

Comment: Will fail in 2.x (Will always be the smallest)

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, @JBernardo: I wasn't suggesting comparing to `None` directly. Have added code to illustrate my intention.

Comment: You could compare to a string (only 2.x) o something like 
`class Biggest:
 def __gt__(self,x):return True`
for 3.x and 2.x

Comment: You *could* … doesnt mean you *should*!